# A single MonoGame code base that deploys to IOS, Android and Windows Phone.

Tags: xamarin, monogame, multiplatform

Is it possible to write one single code base using the MonoGame framework and have it compile on the following platforms: Android, IOS and Windows Phone?

Comment: The Xamarin Sharing Code Options page is a good read. Portable class libraries would be nice, but they don't really work. For the most part file linking is the way to go. http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/building_cross_platform_applications/sharing_code_options/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this, I have done this for my game Tokyo Hosto for the following platforms:
- iOS
- Android
- Windows Phone
- Windows 8 Metro
- Xbox 360
- OUYA
- Playstation Mobile

I first created the XNA projects, coded them to about 90% and when there was a lull in development (because I was waiting for animation to be sent to me) I started work on a MonoGame port. I didn't do anything particularly clever, instead of copying in my source files I linked them in. This meant there was a single set of code used for each platform.

I simply used compiler directives to iron out the platform specific details.

Comment: you said to me that 90% of the code is the same but with witch langage did you write the 90% of the code(is it c# ?) and what about the 10% of the other code?

Comment: 100% of the code was C#, what I meant was 90% of the code was unchanged for different platforms.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have one single code base for MonoGame projects that deploy to iOS, Android and Windows phone. According to the [MonoGame](http://monogame.net/downloads) website you'll need to use two different IDE's, Mono Develop for iOS, Visual Studio for Windows Phone and Visual Studio or Mono Develop for android.

The good news is that the code you write will be mostly reusable but there maybe some small tweaks.

I'd recommend reading around the MonoGame [documentation](http://monogame.net/documentation).

Comment: Could you not, technically, have one code base with 2+ project files to let the different IDEs run?

Comment: That is true, I suppose you could have objects and interfaces that are not implementation specific. That could actually be quite useful.